# How can I run some code when a submit fails due to an input being required?

Tags: javascript, html, form-submit, required

How can I run some code when a submit fails due to an `input` being required and still have the `alert` (with "Please fill out this field") occur? Is there some sort of submit attempt event, or how do I get my submit event to run if a required input is left blank?

**Desired Effect:**

1. user submits form with an empty required input (submit event normally)
2. let browser alert user that required input is empty (default behavior of required attribute)
3. run some other logic function

**Use Case:** I would like to take advantage of the required attribute which scrolls to and `alerts` the user of a required field; however, this prevents the submit listener from running all together. I want the rest of my form logic to run.

```js
var logicFunction = function () { alert('working'); };

var form = document.getElementById('test');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  // want to be able to run something here while still displaying the message
  // "Please fill out this field" caused by the required attribute on the input element
  event.preventDefault();
  logicFunction();
});
```

```html
<form id="test">
  <input type="text" placeholder="leave this blank" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: try adding a `novalidate` attribute to your `form`. That shouldn't stop the individual elements from validating, and should run the submit event handler.

Answer (score 0):

you would need to restructure your setup and handle "errors" manually,
when a field is required on a html level and left empty, the submit button isn't actually fired.

```js
var form = document.getElementById('test');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  if(text01.value == '')  submit.innerHTML = "That's empty";
  else submit.innerHTML = "That's not empty.";
  
  event.preventDefault();
  
  // want to be able to run something here while still displaying the message
  // "Please fill out this field" caused by the required attribute on the input element
});
```

```html
<form id="test">
  <input id="text01" type="text" placeholder="leave this blank">
  <input type="submit">
  <div id="submit"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: so you are saying it's not possible?

Comment: It is possible, but not when using HTML level required attribute on the input, the submit isn't actually "clicked" if the required field is empty, so the javascript isn't initiated and so, it doesn't run.

Comment: I acknowledged that the submit event does not run when a required attribute is on an input element that is empty. What I am looking for is if there is a way to still run an event when this occurs, and not how to restructure my code. So your answer is that it is not possible.